# Unable to select text boxes in selenium webdriver through XPath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

My HTML

```
<table border="2" style="background:gray">
<tbody>
<td class="std">
<input id="ActQ1Revenue" type="text" name="amount" disabled="disabled" maxlength="20" style="background:wheat">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="atd">
<input id="ActAprRevenue" type="text" name="amount" maxlength="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="atd">
<input id="ActMayRevenue" type="text" name="amount" maxlength="20">
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My XPath

```
//input[@type='text'][@disabled!='disabled']
```

I want to select the text boxes who are not disabled and I use above XPath but this is not working any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change expression so

```
//input[@type='text' and not(@disabled ='disabled')]
```